# Multiple calling of same function in python

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm trying to write simple GUI game in python using tkinter library. I want to generate random numbers and after each generation i want to delete this number. I put my function into a for loop so i want to call it 3 times, but it works just when i call it first. It generates the number then delete it and do not generate a new number again. Could you please explain what is the problem, i am really new to python.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import*

def blink():
    number.config(text=randint(1,10))
    number.after(2000, lambda: number.config(text=' ')) 


root = Tk()

number = Label(root,width=20,height=10)
number.pack()

for i in range(3):
    blink()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But you just generate number 3 times and after that start the main loop, but in the "number" stored only the last one because everytime you rewrite the previous.

Comment: @vZ10 you should elaborate and put that in an answer.

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate a random number, after 2 seconds delete it. Do this for each time the function is called?

Comment: @Nae Yes,exactly.

Comment: `after()` executes function only once - you run some `lamba` which doesn't uses  `after()` to execute function again. better use `after(2000, blink)` and count inside `blick` how many times it was executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after()` executes function only once and you run some `lambda` which doesn't uses `after()` to execute function again. Better use after`(2000, blink)` and inside `blink` count how many times it was executed

**EDIT:** you can use two functions with `after()`

`blink` will use `after` to call `remove` and `remove` will use `after` to call `blink`.

This way you can use it two different times to display and to hide the number.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

def blink():
    number.config(text=randint(1,10))
    number.after(2000, remove) 

def remove():
    global repeat

    number.config(text='')

    repeat -= 1
    if repeat > 0:
        number.after(2000, blink) 

repeat = 3
root = tk.Tk()

number = tk.Label(root, width=20, height=10)
number.pack()

blink()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but after each number is generated i need to delete it from the screen, wait 2 seconds more and then generate it again. How i can do this?Could you help me please?

Comment: in `blink` use `after` to call own function `remove` and in `remove` use `after` to call `blink` again. This way you can control how long it is displayer and how long you have to wait for next number.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to build a list of values you want to display, and just display them one after the other:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import*

display = ['', randint(1,10), '', randint(1,10), '', randint(1,10)]

def blink():
    if display:
        number.config(text=display.pop())
        number.after(2000, blink)

root = Tk()

number = Label(root,width=20,height=10)
number.pack()

blink()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I like this idea with list :) If in list use tuples `(text, time)` then it can display every text with different time :) Almost like slide show.

Answer (score 1):

See below example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def blink():
    if lbl['text']:
        lbl['text'] = ''
    else:
        lbl['text'] = random.randint(1, 10)
        lbl.after(1000, blink)


root = tk.Tk()


lbl = tk.Label(root)
lbl.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="button", command=blink).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When the button is pressed it generates a random number if there's not one already, and it removes the number if there's already one.

The function also calls itself after 1s recursively if it generated new number, thus removing the number.